# Internal error while querying the host monitor

Tags: azure, cloudera

I have used used Cloudera's [Azure Resource Manager template][1] to deploy a Cloudera cluster on Azure. the cluster got created OK (took about 35minutes) however on visiting Cloudera Manager I see "Internal error while querying the Host Monitor" and the charts are displaying "QUERY ERROR". I assume these two problems are related.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Given this has been spun up from an ARM template I assumed that stuff would "just work" so I'm surprised to see on first blush that none of the charts display any info. 
I'm a bit stumped how to progress and where to begin an investigation so any clue would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, fixed by restarting the Management Service as per https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Charts-error-Internal-error-while-querying-the-Host-Monitor/td-p/31328